# powerpivot, finding x,y coords based on a 3rd column-minesweeper

Tags: powerpivot, dax

So,
I have a dataset of X,Y coords with a sample result. what i would like to be able to do is add 4 columns (north, south, east & west). These columns will test if i have a positive result in the sample to the north, south, east and west.

It is kinda like the old windows game minesweeper. I want to find how many 'mines' my block is touching.

(hope this table makes sense)

x/y 1   2   3   4
1   t   t   f   f
2   t   t   f   t
3   f   f   f   t
4   t   f   t   f

my problem is getting the syntax to do this.In my head it goes something like this for the block to the north:

if [sample]="true" find sample that has ([x]+1,[y]=[y]) and check if [sample]="true" if true=1

Any help would be appreciated

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure, I understand your scenario correctly but I'll give it a shot because I loved to play minesweeper back in the days =).

I assume the following mine field (0 = no mine; 1 = mine):

0 1 0 
 0 1 0 
 1 0 0

in PowerPivot I would represent the data like this:

X | Y | hasmine 
1 | 1 | 1 
1 | 2 | 0 
1 | 3 | 0 
2 | 1 | 0 
2 | 2 | 1 
2 | 3 | 1 
3 | 1 | 0 
3 | 2 | 0 
3 | 3 | 0

Based on this table structure I would e.g. create a pivottable with x in rows and y in columns and create measures for the current cell (filters applied by pivottable), the cell to the north (y+1), east (x+1), etc. (filteres would be set in the measures) and a sum of the neighbouring cells of interest (north+east+...).

Hope that helps.

Comment: yea, i have my table like yours with the x,y,'mine'.
i cant change my pivot table to the set up you suggest as i have a lot more results that go with each sample and i have over 10k sample results

Comment: is it an option for you to use Power Query to reshape/enhance the table structure? If so, I might have an idea.

Comment: There is a lot of other information that goes with it. So I would want to keep the take the same. I want be able to see  how many 'mines' a  'mine' is touching. This example in excel `D1=IFERROR(--(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$17=A2-1)/($B$2:$B$17=B2),$C$2:$C$17)),"")` works in excel